# Basecamp API - post answer to a Q?

Tags: basecamp

We're using basecamp 3 for daily progress monitoring. My problem is always having to log in, click a bunch of times, check the date and then doing what I went there to do. I know it goes against the intended use, but I don't always care what others are doing.

[image]

I tried using the basecamp API for *responding* to a question, but I haven't been able to find how.

Their API docs only list getting questions/question answers, not posting them:

- https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api/blob/master/sections/questions.md#questions
- https://github.com/basecamp/bc3-api/blob/master/sections/question_answers.md#question-answers

CAN this be done? or can questions / question answers only be retrieved, not added via the API?

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, questions and question answers can only be retrieved, not added via the API, sorry!

Comment: Any idea if/when this will become available?

Comment: Has this changed?